# error using result returned from angular service (undefined)

Tags: angular, service

So I have two variables in my Typescript class:

```
private myServiceSubscription: Subscription;
myVar: myDto[] = [];
```

In the ctor:

```
this.myServiceSubscription = this.deliveryPointService
        .getPostalAddresses()
        .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

I can see the expected result returned from the service in the console log (a list with two items)
However, if I use another subscribe instead:

```
.subscribe(result => this.myVar);
```

and (outside the subscribe):
    console.log(this.myVar[0]);

then I notice this.myVar is undefined.

Why does console.log(result) show the right result, but this.myVar does not?

This is in angular 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, you don't do anything with the result of your service method. You have to assign the returned item to your variable:

```
.subscribe(result => {
   this.myVar = result;
   console.log(this.myVar);
});
```

Comment: That was the point. I wanted to do something with that variable, but if I do as you said and then in the next statement, after `this.myServiceSubscription ...` I want to use this.myVar, it shows as undefined. It's AS IF myVar has a value only inside that subscribe? But I need it outside, later.

Comment: The reason you have a subscribe is that what you are doing is asynchronous. If you try to access `myVar` before your method has returned, you'll get undefined

Comment: I try to access it just after my method, not before

Comment: It does not matter. The essence of an asynchronous operation is that it does not block the thread of execution, it does not *wait* for that operation to finish before going on to the next line. Have a look at how [async programming](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html) works in JS